# firebase: Delete a provider using admin sdk

Tags: firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

Using Admin-sdk, Is there a way to delete a particular provider from a user record in firebase?

For eg:
Assume a given user has the following providers linked to his account

1. password
2. google.com
3. facebook.com

Say, I would like to revoke the user's ability to login via facebook to his account. Can this be done using admin sdk.

I could only find an api to unlink a provider (which is client side api. This will require the firebase-issued-idToken of the user).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure when this ability was added in admin sdk, but it seems in version 8.1.0 you can achieve this using the following:

```
UserRecord.UpdateRequest updateRequest = new UserRecord.UpdateRequest(ssoId);
// remove/unlink social login providers
updateRequest.setProvidersToUnlink(Arrays.asList("google.com", "facebook.com", "apple.com"));            

FirebaseAuth.getInstance().updateUser(updateRequest);
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's an API to unlink a provider in the Admin SDK. It **does** exist in the [REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth#section-unlink-provider), but there too it seems to only exist for the current user.

But I also don't think it would help much, as the user can always call the API to link that provider with your configuration data - even if your application code doesn't. So while it is useful to be able to unlink a provider from your code, it won't be a permanent revoke, which seems to be what you're after. That would only be possible for all users by disabling the Facebook provider completely.